# Escolher um arquivo em uma pasta e salvá-lo como texto automaticamente

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Quero fazer um código VBA que abra uma planilha específica e salve-a como texto tabulado. Estou com esse código formulado

```
 Sub gerararquivotxt()

Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As string

'permitir escolher só um arquivo
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
'abrir a caixa de diálogo
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
'determinar a escolha
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'pegar o caminho do arquivo selecionado
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
        End If
'exportar arquivo selecionado como texto
strPath.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\USER-NOTE\Downloads\PLANILHA_RECEBIMENTO_MENSAL.txt", _
        FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: E qual erro você recebe ?

Comment: para o strPath.saveAs "Qualificador inválido"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você estava tentando Salvar uma string.
 
Precisaria Abrir o Workbook, Salvá-lo como, então Fechá-lo;

```
Sub GerarArquivoTXT()
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String

    'permitir escolher só um arquivo
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    'abrir a caixa de diálogo
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    'determinar a escolha
    If intChoice <> 0 Then
        'pegar o caminho do arquivo selecionado
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    Dim wb As Workbook        
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'exportar arquivo selecionado como texto
    wb.SaveAs Filename:= _
            "C:\Users\USER-NOTE\Downloads\PLANILHA_RECEBIMENTO_MENSAL.txt", _
            FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False,  AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito. Ele pede confirmação se quer salvar mesmo o arquivo, tem como eliminar esse passo?

Comment: Encontrei esta resposta, e mesclei com o código acima, veja se ele salva sem pedir novamente confirmação. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14634781/194717

Comment: Perfeito! valeu demais!